# como mostrar cuantas veces se repite una temperatura en un rango de un mes en c++?

Tags: c++, c, contador

hola necesito hacer un programa que al ingresar 30 temperaturas de un mes me muestre cuantas veces se han repetido las temperaturas, logre hacer el programa pero no muestra cuantas veces se ha repetido y necesito hacerlo con arreglos de una dimensión.
esto es lo que hice, ayuda :c
''''
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

''''

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string diasmes[30] =
    { "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30" };



    float tempmes[30];
    int cuentatemp[30];


    /* captura de temperaturas de los días del mes */
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        cout << "Cual fue la temperatura del dia " << diasmes[i] << " ?";
        cin >> tempmes[i];
    }


    cout << endl;


    /* Mostrar las temperaturas de los días del mes */


    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        cout << "la temperatura del dia " << diasmes[i] << " =" << tempmes[i] << endl;
        cuentatemp[i] = 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: Siempre es recomendable poner el código en texto, y no en imágenes. En algunos trabajos o lugares especiales, muchos usuarios del sitio no pueden ver imágenes. ¿Podrías colocar el código en tu pregunta?

Comment: me dice que no es compatible el codigo y no sabia como ponerlo

Comment: ya quedo el codigo

Comment: Deberías poner el programa completo. Lo que has puesto ni se entiende. Tienes  "cuenta_ocurrencias_digitos"  que está flotando por el centro del programa. No está claro ni tiene un orden coherente. Quizá no copió bien. Vuelve a ponerlo.

Comment: listo es que estaba experimentando con codigos que encontre en internet pero hasta ahi me corre guardando las temperaturas y mostrandolas dia por dia solo me falta agregar algo para que me muestre cuantas veces se repiten las temperaturas que ingrese

Answer (score 1):

Con un solo arreglo resuelves.

```
float temperaturas[30];
```

Declaras un arreglo de temperaturas donde cada posición del arreglo tendrá el valor de temperatura correspondiente, siendo esa posición del arreglo la que te dará el día del mes, ejemplo:

```
temperaturas[1] = 10;
```

En la posición 1 del arreglo estás guardando una temperatura de 10, y como en **C++**, los arreglos empiezan en la posición 0, lo que estás haciendo se lee como que en el segundo día del mes hubo una temperatura de 10.

Dicho esto tu código para entrar las temperaturas quedaría de esta forma:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   cout << "Temperatura del día " << i + 1 << "?";
   cin >> temperaturas[i];
}
```

Aquí haces un **ciclo for** donde en cada posición del **arreglo temperaturas** vas a guardar la temperatura, recuerda que la posición es precisamente el día. Cuando imprimo con **cout** pongo **i + 1**, ya que los arreglos en **C++** empiezan en el índice 0, por tanto el índice 0 sería el día 1, el índice 1 sería el día 2 y el índice 29 sería el día 30.

Ahora para saber cuántas veces se repite una temperatura en un mes harías una función:

```
int TemperaturaRepetida(float arreglo[], float t)
{
   int total = 0;

   for(int i = 0;i < 30; i++)
   {
      if(arreglo[i] == t)
      {
         total++;
      }
   }

   return total;
}
```

Esta función recibe dos parámetros, el arreglo de temperaturas y la temperatura que va a servir para ver cuántas veces se repite en el arreglo, y va a devolver un entero que es precisamente la cantidad de veces que esa temperatura se repite en el arreglo.

Dentro de esta función se hace un **ciclo for** que va a recorrer el arreglo y va a preguntar si hay algún valor del arreglo que sea igual a t, de ser igual incremento la variable total.

Al salir del ciclo retorno el valor que tiene la **variable total**, siendo este valor la cantidad de veces que se repite una temperatura en el arreglo.

Para utilizar esta función hacemos lo siguiente:

```
int total = TemperaturaRepetida(temperaturas, valor);
```

Aquí llamas a la función que previamente se había creado pasándole por parámetros tu arreglo de temperaturas y valor, que hipotéticamente sería, la temperatura a buscar cuantas veces se repite en el arreglo.

Después imprimirlas el contenido de la **variable total**.

Comment: disculpa en "arreglo" y "t" van mis variables? porque me dice el programa que no esta definido

Comment: "Arreglo" y "t" son los nombres que le di a los parámetros de mi función, no entiendo tu duda, no obstante revisa lo nuevo que puse

Answer (score -2):

El código que posteas puede simplificarse a una función principal y la función Temperatura repetida que postea el usuario.

En el proceso principal se van pidiendo las temperaturas y se las van almacenando con un bloque `for` al arreglo. Después se llama a la función que cuenta cuántas veces se repite una temperatura en un mes y devuelve un valor que se escribirá en la función principal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int TemperaturaRepetida(float arreglo[], float t);

int main()
{

    float temperaturas[30];
    temperaturas[1] = 10;
    float t;

    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        cout << "Cual fue la temperatura del d¡a " << i + 1 << "? ";
        cin >> temperaturas[i];
    }

    cout << endl <<endl;

    cout << "Ingrese la temperatura a saber cuantas veces se repite en el mes" << endl;
    cin >> t;

    cout << TemperaturaRepetida(temperaturas, t) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int TemperaturaRepetida(float temperaturas[], float t)
{
   int total = 0;

   for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
   {
      if(temperaturas[i]==t)
      {
         total++;
      }
   }

   return total;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa pero no veo ninguna diferencia entre tu respuesta y la que di, cual es tu nuevo aporte

Comment: Que está todo compaginado en un mismo código, es un programa completo, no son respuestas sueltas.

Comment: Me vas a tener que volver a disculpar, pero realmente no veo aporte,  lo que hay es redundancia de respuesta, además el usuario debe tener un conocimiento mínimo básico, tampoco es que uno le dé la comidita en la boca

Comment: No te disculpes, no hay de qué. Si, usuario debe tener un conocimiento mínimo básico, pero a veces ni con eso el código sale, a mi me costó un poco sacarlo.

Comment: Mira, en todo caso aclarar eso me toca a mi que fui quien dio la respuesta original, no es copiar la respuesta que di y pegarla como nueva respuesta, no te pongas bravo, reporte tu respuesta a un moderador para que todo se aclare

Comment: Cuando copias codigo de otra persona, aunque sea para ponerlo todo junto, lo correcto es que hagas las atribuciones del caso y las aclaraciones. Siendo que tu codigo es una copia del que puso OP (lo cual no es problema) + el de otra respuesta (la cual no es tuya), entonces deberias aclarar en tu respuesta que ese codigo no lo escribiste vos, que lo copiaste de otra respuesta, que esa respuesta es la correcta, votarla a favor y si queres agregar otra respuesta, que no hay problema, aclarar porque agregas otra.